# Android Designer like "Interface Builder"?

Tags: android, layout, designer

We are beginning to learn Android, converting our iPhone apps over.

There is a rudimentary editor for layouts in Eclipse, but it's not very good. Is there a visual designer that would be on par with the iPhone "Interface Builder" ?

Comment: the latest Android Interface Builder is quite good. They've made lots of improvements to it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such builder yet for Android,

Check out [droiddraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) and try to make the most out from Eclipse builder, those are the best and only interface builders. Anyway once you get in, you won't spend to much time creating lots of interfaces, as you will reuse them or the inbuilt components like preferencescreen.

When developing and thinking about layouts, think them as they were like HTML layouts.

Comment: Google should spend some money making a good Interface Builder for Android. Coding to make user interface objects is soooooo 1980.

Comment: Android has everything to compete with iOS...except UI

Answer (score 2):

App Inventor looks interesting, but it's still in beta and you need to request access: 
[http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/](http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/)

It seems to have a nice interface for building Android UI's and actually generates other code such as networking and database code.

Comment: the editor is nice, yes, but you cannot reuse what you create with sdk or monodroid.

Comment: Looks like WYSIWYG for Android apps. Not much useful for professionals.